# Removing an element in an array and then using map to make it dynamic React

Tags: reactjs

I want to remove an element from the array arradd. Currently, I am able to use the id which is in incremented order and remove the element with the help of splice. However, this method is not dynamic since it does not return the map immideately. How do I make this dynamic?

```
const handleremove = (e) => {
arradd.splice(e.target.id, 1);
} 
 
return(        
  {arradd.map((a, idx) => {
   return <div key={a}>
  <HoriContainer><Texty>{a}</Texty><img  id={idx} idx={idx++} onClick={handleremove}src= 
  {cross}></img></HoriContainer> 
   </div>
```

Comment: You can use `array#filter`.

Comment: @HassanImam I was trying to do that, but I am not sure how I can do that in my situation. Could you please provide an example with my code?

Comment: Please add sample `arradd`. Is `arradd`  a state variable?

Comment: The object you shared is invalid. It should be something like this `['abbas','calton']`.

Comment: @HassanImam It's a state variable. An example of this would be ['abbas','ahmed','yousef']

Comment: If you have `arradd` as array and you are getting `e.target.id` as a value in array, then you could use `const output = arradd.filter(name => name !== e.target.id);` and you can then set your state with the `output` value.

Comment: @HassanImam thank you so much! this worked :) I had to use arrand[e.target.id] though since it represents the index of the name in the array

Comment: Cool. Glad to help you.